# Is there a way to display additional textFields if a user clicks on a button inside a single view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have a fairly complex form inside a view controller that requires a few text fields to be filled out for some users and many other text fields for other users. Is there a way to start the view controller with a couple of text fields, and then if a user clicks on a button('MORE')...the other text fields will display?

Comment: Yup, create a view with all additional TextFields. Initially don't add it to your VC/hide it. When user taps button then in its actions, add it your Viewcontroller's view or unhide it, depending on your approach.

Comment: A better way would be to use a collapsable TableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all the textFields in the View in Interface Builder and set the attribute `myTextField.hidden = true`. When you click the `more`button then you can set the hidden attribute to false.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please mark the answer as selected answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to start the view controller with a couple of text fields, and then if a user clicks on a button('MORE')...the other text fields will display?

Sure. When the user taps the button, you can insert the additional fields. You might do that by creating the new fields and inserting them into the existing view, or loading some different view and setting the view controller's view to that new view (and of course populating the new view with the user's data). Or the fields in question could exist in the original view but be hidden.

A view controller is fully in charge of the view it manages, including all subviews of that view, so it can really do whatever it likes to move, add, or remove views, controls, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can add text field at runtime by dynamically creating them. But there is another possibility to design these fields in a separate `UIView` using IB and add this `UIView` to `ViewController.view` whenever needed. This way you will save the positioning effort of each textfield element.